# how to change nth element of the string

Tags: c#, string

i have a code in c# like below

```
string s = new string('~',25);
int ind = 5;
s[ind] = 'A';
```

it gives an error

> Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read

so what is the problem, and how can i fix it.

Comment: strings are immutable in C#, so you need to use a stringBuilder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strings are immutable - you can't change an existing one.

Two options:

- Use `StringBuilder`, e.g.

  ```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(new string('~', 25));
  builder[5] = 'A';
  string result = builder.ToString();
  ```
- Build a new string from a char array:

  ```
  char[] chars = new string('~', 25).ToCharArray();
  chars[5] = 'A';
  string result = new string(chars);
  ```

In both cases you could populate the mutable data without building a new string to start with if you want - that would involve more code, but would probably be more efficient.

Alternatively, you can take substrings and concatenate them together, as per another answer ...there are basically lots of ways of tackling this. Which one is appropriate will depend on your actual use case.

Answer (score 1):

Following [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx):

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it appear as if you can do this.

Take a look at `StringBuilder` class or use `char` array instead.

Answer (score 0):

C# strings are immutable which means that once constructed the cannot be changed. Try using an array of chars instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
s = s.Substring(0, ind) + "A" + s.Substring(ind + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stringbuilder, in which you can assign to the indexer:

```
StringBuilder sb = s;
int ind = 5;
sb[ind] = 'A';
s = sb.ToString();
```