# How do I replace the first occurrence of a Substring in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, replace

I am having string variable as follow

```
 string pctSign = "\0\0\0";
```

I want to replace first two characters with "%"

```
i.e. Final o/p:- pctSign="%\0\0";
```

How to do this with String.Replace?

Comment: Try using `Substring` (possibly in combination with `IndexOf`) instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I replace the *first instance* of a string in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Option 1
var result = "%" + pctSign.Remove(0, 2);

// Option 2
var result = "%" + pctSign.Substring(2);

// Option 3
var regex = new Regex("^\\0");
var result = regex.Replace(pctSign, "%");
```

If you absolutely want to user `String.Replace()` then you can write your own extension method:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static String Replace(this string self, 
                                      string oldString, string newString, 
                                      bool firstOccurrenceOnly = false)
    {
        if ( !firstOccurrenceOnly )
            return self.Replace(oldString, newString);

        int pos = self.IndexOf(oldString);
        if ( pos < 0 )
            return self;

        return self.Substring(0, pos) + newString 
               + self.Substring(pos + oldString.Length);
    }
}

// Usage:
var result = pctSign.Replace("/0", "%", true);
```

Comment: isn't there any way to write this using Replace?

Comment: @AmolKolekar there are two overloads for `String.Replace()` both of which replace **all** occurrences of the given string or char. String doesn't provide a `Replace` method that only replaces a specific occurrence.

Comment: Updated my answer and added a way to use `String.Replace` anyway.

Comment: I got simple solution here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990093/how-to-change-nth-element-of-the-string

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var pctSign = "\0\0\0";
var result = string.Format("%{0}", pctSign.Substring(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = pctSign.Substring(2, pctSign.Length);
s = "%" + s;
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean only first two then

```
pctSign = "%"+pctSign.substring(2);
```

Comment: This will remove all occurrences of `/0` because this is what `pctSign.substring(0,2)` evaluates to.