# Change the second character in a string

Tags: c#

```
string input = "testeeeeeee";
char[] temp = input.ToCharArray();
var test = Regex.Replace(input.Replace(temp[1].ToString(), "@").Trim(), @"\s+", " ");
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

This is the code I have now, I want my second char on a string to be replaced with "@" , now is the problem that every e will be replaced in @ , how to fix it that only the second char will be replaced and nothing more?

Comment: Strings are immutable. You may use either StringBuilder, a character array or just concatenate two substrings. Find a very similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5990142/6521550

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to just assign a new value to the second char:

```
var input = "testeeeeeee".ToCharArray();
input[1] = '@';

var result = new string(input);
```

You'd want to do something like `input[1]` = `@` on the original string and not the `char[]` but as strings are immutable you cannot change it and the indexer is read-only.

---

Another way (which I think is less advisable):

```
var input = "testeeeeeee";
var result =  input[0] + "@" + string.Concat(input.Skip(2));
```

*For the second way it is cleaner to use `SubString` to get the string from the second index until the end*

Comment: It needs to be chainable if possible , sorry for not telling

Comment: Create an extension method then @JordiMutsaers

Comment: @JordiMutsaers - Did this help you solve the posted question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) function

```
string input = "testeeeeeee";
string new_input = input.Substring(0, 1) + "@" + input.Substring(2, input.Length)
```